# Como o SO(pt) lida com o caso de utilizadores falecidos?

Tags: debate, suporte, comportamento, stackexchange, autoria

Bom pessoal, sei que é meio que bizarra a questão, mas é isso:

Como o SO(pt) lida com o caso de utilizadores falecidos?

Após ao conhecimento de um ou vários moderadores, os dados dele são apagados?

Comment: Isto provavelmente seria útil até no MSE :) Ou inútil se considerar que já não é mais um problema para este usuário :D

Comment: Não tem nada bizarro: [Death and the internet - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_and_the_internet) . . . @bigown, já tem um Meta.SE: [How should a user's death be handled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38742/185667)

Comment: Legal, acho que é só traduzir para cá. E deixo registrado que sou doador de órgãos do meu corpo ou que saíram do meu cérebro :D

Comment: Se alguém se animar a traduzir, que deixe um comentário para evitar trabalho duplo... Eu voto no @Cold :) Aliás, não consigo pensar num *nick* melhor para haver levantado o assunto.

Comment: O lance nesses casos é alterar o `local` pra `/dev/null` no perfil do usuário.

Comment: @Bacco ou setar para `void`. ou `null-pointer`...

Comment: Se eu morrer, eu quero uma fita amarela gravada com o nome dela, um jazz-funeral daqueles que se faz em Nova Orleans e que meu corpo seja doado para a ciência. Não necessariamente nessa ordem.

Comment: @Renan, [you just won the internet](http://youtu.be/utUzUVEs90s) :) Morrer à brasileira é isso aí!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Essa é a política sobre o assunto desde o trágico [suicídio](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2013/01/aaron-swartz/) do [Aaron Swartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4300/aaronsw).

**Nós decidimos que, em um site como o nosso, implementar um processo formal de respeito à memória de um falecido pode acabar causando mais problemas do que o desejável em um momento assim.**

Os motivos:

1. **Algo assim não é tão necessário em um site como o nosso, ao contrário de outras redes *mais tendentes à socialização*.**
   Sites como o Facebook são utilizados por muitas pessoas como uma forma de se manter atualizado sobre conhecidos e amigos. Dessa maneira, estabelecer uma maneira de noticiar o falecimento de alguém presta um serviço à essas pessoas. Além de evitar situações desconfortáveis, como um desejo de "feliz aniversário" para alguém que já faleceu, dando a outras pessoas a desagradável tarefa de comunicar o acontecido. Isso não quer dizer que seja impossível criar relações importantes aqui, e não queremos minimizar a dor de perder alguém que você conheceu, passou a respeitar ou amar aqui, mas a *maioria* das interações no SE são de natureza mais informal, especialmente fora do chat.
2. **Ter certeza absoluta do falecimento de alguém é muito, muito difícil.**
   Em casos não tão notórios como o do Aaron, devemos nos preocupar com a possibilidade de alguém agindo de ma fé, brincadeiras de mau gosto ou casos de assédio. Mesmo que nosso processo seja reversível, marcar aluguém como "morto" pode afetar outros de maneira grave. Em lugares como o Facebook é necessário, além de comprovar relação com o usuário, enviar alguma espécie de obituário. (Sabemos de casos próximos em que pessoas não conseguiram por não terem apresentado um obituário público, e o Facebook argumentou que o certificado de óbito poderia ser forjado facilmente).
3. **Mesmo que seja possível confirmar a morte, é difícil saber qual seria o desejo do falecido.**
   Esse é o motivo mais signicativo. O que aconteceria se o conjuge pedisse que a conta permanecesse ativa, recebendo votos e prestando ajuda mesmo póstumamente, mas os pais do usuário se sentissem desconfortáveis e pedissem que a conta fosse paralisada?

No caso do Aaron, ele deixou uma espécie de  testamento virtual:

> Determino Sean B. Parker como responsável por organizar tudo isso. (E, Sean, se você apagar qualquer coisa, eu vou te assombrar pra sempre!)
>
> Peço que o conteúdo de todos os meus drives seja publicado em aaronsw.com ...
> ([Fonte](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/continuity))

Nesse caso, permitir que qualquer pessoa além do Sean Palmer tivesse voz sobre a conta do Aaron seria *contradizer seu desejo explicíto*, e isso é a última coisa que queremos.

Obviamente, nos colocamos à disposição dos amigos e familiares de usuários que falecerem, e tentaremos atender aos pedidos que acreditarmos honrar sua memória e desejos. Nossa posição, no entanto, é continuar acreditando que os usuários que partirem desejariam o mesmo que desejavam em vida. Que seus posts ajudem aqueles que precisarem e que seus perfis representem o que eles determinaram quando ainda estavam vivos.

Sei que muitos dos que tem interesse nesse assunto foram motivados pelo caso do Aaron, então gostaria de dizer: <sup>1</sup>

- Jeff Atwood, nosso co-fundador, mais conhecido como [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com), escreveu um [post sincero, forte e sensível sobre o falecimento do Aaron Swartz](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2013/01/the-end-of-ragequitting.html).
- Notícias de suicídios podem servir de gatilhos para outras pessoas sofrendo de depressão. Se você está enfrentando problemas, ligue para esses números:

  - 141 - [Como Vai Você (Centro de Valorização à Vida)](http://www.cvv.org.br/) [Brasil]
  - 112 - [Serviço Nacional de Socorro](http://www.spsuicidologia.pt/sobre-o-suicidio/telefones-uteis) [Portugal]

  Eles estão lá 24 horas por dia, sempre dispostos a ajudar. Não posso prometer que vão resolver tudo, mas certamente vão te ajudar.

---

<sup>1</sup> Essa parte está fora de contexto na nossa pergunta, mas está traduzida em prol da plenitude do texto.
<sup>2</sup> Traduzido de [How should a user's death be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164749/175506)

Answer (score 6):

<sup><sub>Meta-meta-resposta</sub></sup>
Obviamente não sei como vai ser em 2114, mas neste ponto da história somos uma geração onde muitas e muitas e muitas pessoas comuns estão registrando seus momentos pessoais e descobertas profissionais de maneira pública e irrestrita.

Talvez este seja um breve momento de liberdade histórica e dentro de 100 anos nós sejamos um simples *Data Dump*: **`Internet a princípios do Séc. XXI`**.

Quase nunca tenho consciência disso ao escrever algo na grande rede, mas volta e meia, naquele momento de lucidez antes de se entregar ao sono, vem o pensamento "puxa, será que isso fica bem nas minhas memórias?". E na manhã seguinte, você vai lá e tenta deletar aquele post estranho.

Tem gente que tem sorte de ter uma morte planejada, tem gente que tem sorte de ter uma morte súbita e sem dores, tem gente que não tem sorte. Nos seus diversos graus, deixar a chave-mestra da sua vida digital a um par de pessoas próximas é um passo precavido. Mas se não fizer isso, well, mais um problema que se deixa de herança para os amigos e parentes que tem que lidar com o evento.

Comment: *Sábios em vão /
Tentarão decifrar /
O eco de antigas palavras /
Fragmentos de cartas, poemas /
Mentiras, retratos /
Vestígios de estranha civilização*. O que você escreveu me lembrou dessa música. E sempre que lembro dessa música me impressiona a habilidade do Chico Buarque por ter conseguido encaixar a palavra "escafandristas" numa letra de música.

Comment: Pô, @bfav, é um sambinha seu? *Doce cavaquinho?* Nada a ver, mas me lembra o Borges ou o HP Lovecraft...

Comment: Dá um refresh na página, é do Chico Buarque :)

Comment: Chico tem seu panteão a parte. Você fez trapaça de mod burlando o grace period :p (eixo non pot ser) . . .  Como diria o Silvio Santos, *Qual é a música*?

Comment: Eu não lembro o título, mas dá um google por "chico escafandristas" que você acha :) Ah, os mods têm grace period eterno em comentários \o/

Comment: [**Futuros Amantes**](http://youtu.be/LOwQLarDhvI). Chico é gênio, Chico é lindo, as moças vão adorar, mas Chico você já é bem feio, sem camisola e num videoclip anos 80... OMG!

Answer (score 4):

De acordo com o [link postado pelo brasofilo nos comentários](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38742/how-should-a-users-death-be-handled), não se faz nada. Não que o pessoal do SO seja insensível a isso, pelo contrário... É só que o Stack Exchange em geral não é uma rede social. Se o SE tomasse qualquer atitude relacionada ao falecimento de algum usuário, isso trária mais malefícios do que benefícios.

Vou só fazer um resumão da [resposta mais votada por lá](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164749/221728):

- O foco do SE não é ser uma rede social - o foco aqui são perguntas e respostas, e não o status atual dos usuários;
- É difícil saber com certeza se alguém morreu mesmo ou se a informação não passa de fraude, trollagem ou mero engano;
- Geralmente não se tem como saber qual era o desejo da pessoa quanto as suas contas onlines - pode ser que uma atitude tomada com relação a isso vá contra as vontades da pessoa que se foi.

Vou colocar minha própria opinião agora. O SO é um repositório de informação. A informação é independente do usuário. Seu código continuará funcionando bem (ou não) independente de você estar vivo (ou não). Não há porque associar uma coisa a outra. Se alguém quiser realmente que as pessoas saibam seu status, não acho inadequado ter no perfil aqui um link para o perfil do Facebook. Mas mais que isso seria sair do foco da rede.